# Reading Serial data in Unity from Android app

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, serial-port

I am using Android's [SensoDuino](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.techbitar.android.sensoduino&hl=en) ([Official website](http://www.techbitar.com/sensoduino.html)) app to send sensory data like Accelerometer, gyro etc. using Bluetooth serial communication to Unity in PC. I am using the following code in Unity to receive data -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System;

public class COM : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public SerialPort sp;
    public float data;

    void Start () {
        sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600,Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        Debug.Log ("Connection started");

        if (sp != null) 
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen) 
            {
                sp.Close();
                Debug.Log ("Closing port, because it was already open!");
            }
            else 
            {
                sp.Open();  // opens the connection
                // sets the timeout value before reporting error
                sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                Debug.Log("Port Opened!");
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                print("Port is already open");
            }
            else 
            {
                print("Port == null");
            }
        }

        Debug.Log ("Open Connection finished running");
    }

    void Update () { 
        data = float.Parse( sp.ReadTo ("\r") ) ;
        print ("data = " + data);
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort spl = (SerialPort)sender;
        data = float.Parse( spl.ReadTo ("\r") ) ;
        Debug.Log(data.ToString());
        print ("data = " + data);
    }
}
```

But I am not able to receive any data. The `DataReceiveHandler` is not firing at all. I tried to use `ReadLine()` also, but it freezes Unity.

The format by which SensoDuino sends Accelerometer data is

> 1,104,0.54437256,-0.2632141,9.826126
>
> 1,105,0.56111145,-0.279953,9.8524475
>
> 1,106,0.54556274,-0.2632141,9.833298
>
> 1,107,0.5515442,-0.26081848,9.841675
>
> 1,108,0.5312042,-0.2644043,9.867996

This is a continuous stream and might be the cause of the freeze while using `ReadLine()`.

Please help me to read the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. `ReadLine()` is a blocking call, so I had to use `ReadByte()` to continuously read bytes and convert the data later. To reduce lag, the `ReadByte()` function was called in a thread.

```
 void recData() {
    if ((sp != null) && (sp.IsOpen)) {
        byte tmp;
        string data = "";
        string avalues="";
        tmp = (byte) sp.ReadByte();
        while(tmp !=255) {
            data+=((char)tmp);
            tmp = (byte) sp.ReadByte();
            if((tmp=='>') && (data.Length > 30)){
                avalues = data;
                parseValues(avalues);
                data="";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have made a pretty detailed tutorial [here](http://dil33pm.in/reading-serial-data-in-unity-using-c/)

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem:**
As [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011887/why-dont-serial-ports-work-properly-in-unity). This problem is because Unity's Mono has not a full implementation of SerialPort class.

**The easy solution:**
An easy solution could be to use [this C# library](https://github.com/genielabs/serialport-lib-dotnet) which implements a MessageReceived event. I've tested it on Windows and has worked with no problem.

The library is available in *NuGet*. Then, you could install some Unity plugin as "*Nuget For Unity*" from the asset store and then install and use the library in your game.

**Another solution:**
Another solution could be to implement by yourself a class that reads permanently data in the serial port in another thread and then invokes an event to notify when new data is available.

You could [read this method](https://github.com/genielabs/serialport-lib-dotnet/blob/ba80f43c0adf5638da6dc68bb2afc7616d1db14e/SerialPortLib/SerialPort.cs#L296) from the previously mentioned library to get some inspiration.

Here a copy of the library's serial read method:

```
public delegate void MessageReceivedHandler(byte[] message);
public event MessageReceivedHandler MessageReceived;
void ReaderTask ()
{
    // Will ask for data while connected to the serial port
    while (IsConnected)
    {
        int messageLength = serialPort.BytesToRead;
        if (msglen > 0)
        {
            byte[] message = new byte[messageLength];
            int offset = 0;
            int count = messageLength - offset;
            // Ask data for ever if there is no data yet in the serial port
            while (serialPort.Read(message, offset, count) <= 0)
                ; // noop

            // Check if there are subscribed listeners
            if (MessageReceived != null)
            {
                MessageReceived(message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}

// In the main thread
// Start the Reader task
reader = new Thread(ReaderTask);
reader.Start();
```

Note: I know this question was posted a long time ago but I post this answer here for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why the serial events aren't handled in Unity, this is answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35413397/5386234