# Reading out Serial Port "COM3" in Unity. Connection establishing succesful, but the DataReceiveHandler is not called

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, serial-port

I need to scan QR Code (via Scanner not a Camera). The scanner is sending the data over the Serial Port "COM3" and I need it as a string in Unity. So setting up the connection works fine and without any errors or exceptions, but the system is not registering the my event at the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler. (See code: DataReceiveHandler and everything in it seems nerver to be called)

I use the following Settings to open the Port:

PortName is "COM3"
BaudRate is 19200
PortParity is None
PortBits is 8
PortStopBits is One

As I said, the port opens correctly. I get no errors or exceptions.
Maybe you see something that I don't see.
Thank you!

```
private void Start()
{
    Init();
}

private void Update()
{
    PortIsOpen = SP.IsOpen;
}

private void EstablishPortConnection()
{
    try
    {
        if(SP != null)
        {
            SP.Close();
            SP.Dispose();
            SP = null;
        }

        if(SP == null)
        {
            SP = new SerialPort(PortName, BaudRate, PortParity, PortBits, PortStopBits);
            SP.RtsEnable = true;
            SP.DataReceived += new        SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataRecievedHandler);
            SP.Open();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception _ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error while establishing connection! Error: " + _ex);
    }
}

private void DataRecievedHandler(object _sender,   SerialDataReceivedEventArgs _e)
{
    Debug.Log("DataReceived");
    try
    {
        SerialPort tmpsp = (SerialPort)_sender;
        Debug.Log(tmpsp.ReadLine());
        Message = tmpsp.ReadLine();
    }
    catch(Exception _ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error during message receiving. Error: " + _ex);
    }
}

public void Init()
{
    Message = "";
    EstablishPortConnection();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't serial ports work properly in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011887/why-dont-serial-ports-work-properly-in-unity)

Comment: [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/serial-communication-and-serialport-datareceived-event.139157/) someone implemented such a data polling as mentioned in the duplicate link without using the event

Comment: Do not use handshaking(RTS)!!! It is obsolete and probably won't work because the wire isn't connected in the cable.  You are not getting the event because you are not receiving any data.  Most device will not send data until you first send a command to the device.  So devices will automatically send but you first have to set a special menu item.

Comment: Everything works fine with HTerm and the same device...

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011887/why-dont-serial-ports-work-properly-in-unity

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

You cannot use DataReceived handler in Unity, as it is not implemented by Mono.

You need to do manual port pooling to read, so its best to run it in a seperate thread (as the pooling is blocking). Please see the link provided in the comments by derHugo for more details (anyone with delete rights - feel free to remove this answer, this question is formulated better than the original question so I thought its worth duplicating the answer)